# ng-pattern wrong or not doesn't allow tooltip to be triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{9}$/"` in a input field that render as follow:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="company_taxId" 
    ng-model="company.taxId" 
    required="required" 
    class="input ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-minlength ng-dirty ng-valid-required ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern" 
    style="width:485px;" 
    ng-minlength="9" 
    maxlength="9" 
    ng-maxlength="9" 
    ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{9}$/" 
    placeholder="Ej: 458965879" 
    tooltip="Ej: 458965879" 
    wv-def="Ej: 458965879" 
    tooltip-trigger="focus" 
    tooltip-placement="right" 
    wv-cur="" 
    wv-err="Este valor debería ser un número válido." 
    wv-req="Este campo es requerido" 
    wv-min="Este valor debería tener exactamente 9 caracteres" 
    wv-max="Este valor debería tener exactamente 9 caracteres"
>
```

If pattern fails, for example if I wrote letter instead numbers the message "Este valor debería ser un número válido" should trigger but it's not working and I can't find where the problem is. Is the pattern wrong? What is wrong there?

This is the directive that handle the tooltip trigger:

```
app.directive('validated', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.keyup(function(){
                parent = $('.tooltip');
                target = parent.find('.tooltip-inner'); 
                if( element.hasClass('ng-invalid-required') ){
                    target.html(attrs.wvReq);
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvReq;
                    parent.addClass('error');
                }
                else if( element.hasClass('ng-invalid-email') ){
                    target.html(attrs.wvEml);   
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvEml;
                    parent.addClass('error');   
                }
                else if (element.hasClass('ng-invalid-name-exists')) {
                    target.html(attrs.wvNam);
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvNam;
                    parent.addClass('error');
                }
                else if( element.hasClass('ng-invalid-minlength') ){
                    target.html(attrs.wvMin);   
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvMin;
                    parent.addClass('error');   
                }
                else if( element.hasClass('ng-invalid-maxlength') ){
                    target.html(attrs.wvMax);   
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvMax;
                    parent.addClass('error');
                }
                else if( element.hasClass('ng-invalid') ){
                    target.html(attrs.wvErr);
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvErr;
                    parent.addClass('error');   
                }
                else{
                    target.html(attrs.wvDef);
                    attrs.wvCur = attrs.wvDef;
                    parent.removeClass('error');    
                }
            });

            element.focus(function(){
                //attrs.title = attrs.wvCur;

                setTimeout(function(){
                    parent = $('.tooltip');
                    target = parent.find('.tooltip-inner'); 
                    target.html((attrs.wvCur != "" ? attrs.wvCur : attrs.wvDef));
                    if( attrs.wvCur != attrs.wvDef && attrs.wvCur != "" )
                        parent.addClass('error');
                },5);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

PS: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip for this

Comment: Have you tried setting a `$scope` variable with that regex & then using that variable as the argument to `ng-pattern`?

Comment: @FooL why do that? I mean if for example I have 50 fields and each have different `ng-pattern` then I should set all this in `$scope` at controller? This is insane but answering your doubt, no, I didn't try that

Comment: @j.wittwer this is the error to show by default if I enter letters instead of numbers

Comment: what's `wv-err`? where is it defined?

Comment: @Mosho I already answer that to j.wittwer user

Comment: yeah, but where does it come from?

Comment: @Mosho is just a value I write, see my edit I have added the directive related to this

Comment: Yeah, that's what I, and I assume j.wittwer meant. I don't see where you have a `validated` attribute in the element though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `ng-model` attribute is not optional (as can be seen [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)). You do assign it, but it needs to actually exist in the scope. So you need to supply a scope with a controller as well as a valid variable to reference in `ng-model`.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4JxhQ/3/). You can see that if you remove or otherwise invalidate the scope variable assigned to `ng-model` it stops working.

This will solve the issue, but in general I suggest you achieve what you're trying to do closer to what is shown in angular's docs.

**Edit**: Here is a working version of your code: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4JxhQ/7/)

However, you can't set the element attributes using `attr` like you are trying to do. You have to use `element`. And it doesn't have the tooltip element (you can add it). Again, I *strongly* advise you to take a look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and maybe look at some angular tutorials and examples, and try to rewrite your code in that style.

Comment: What should I wrote in the input in order to see your example in action? I try with `oooooo` and didn't work

Comment: Any suggestions for add this to my directive in order to fix the issue? I mean I get the solution for controller but still don't know how to add to directive and make it to work

Comment: Edited. Take note of my recommendation.